# Converting Integer to Character in Java

Tags: java

I have this program in which in the Switch statement structure, I've calculated an expression and want to pass its result to the stack (which I have implemented in Chars). Now the problem is that I have used

```
            char c;
            int C = 0;
            switch(op)
            {
                case '+':
                {
                    C = B + A;
                    c = (char) C;
                    push(c);
                    break;
                }
                case '-':
                {
                    C = B - A;
                    c = (char) C;
                    push(c);
                    break;
                }
                case '*':
                {
                    C = B * A;
                    c = (char) C;
                    push(c);
                    break;
                }
                case '/':
                {
                    C = B / A;
                    c = (char) C;
                    push(c);
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Now if I print C (which is Integer), it would work just fine, but if I print c (which is char) or I push it to the stack, whatsoever, it would display nothing but empty. I have also used the System.out.println(C) and found out that the calculation ( C = B + A etc) works just fine but the conversion to char (c = (char) C ) does not convert the value.

Any alternative solution would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Character.toChars(integer?)

Comment: For what values of A and B? or more so what is the value of C that you are trying to print? are you trying to print the number of the character value of that number?

Comment: The values of A and B are 2 and 3 respectively. The result should be according to the op which is either +, -, * or /. The variable C (integer) stores the result accurately but I am not able to convert this integer value (C) into char value(c)

Comment: Go the other way when printing, so that you're not trying to print out ASCII 2 or 3 (which aren't printable).  `System.out.println("" + ((int) c));` or anything like that, that converts your char to an int first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Character.forDigit(C, 10)
```

Try this, it should work.

Comment: I did that and it said that the the types are incompatible i.e. Required: char, whereas Found: Char[]

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to print the numerical value of `C` i.e. for the case `2 + 3` and want to print `5`, but when doing the cast of `(char) 5` you get the control character `ENQ` ([See ASCII Characters](http://ascii.cl/)) which will most likely not be printable by the console.

As given in another answer try

```
Character.forDigit(C, 10)
```

But this will only work for single digit answers. If more digits are required you might want to use a string and try

```
String.valueOf(C)
```

Comment: you are right, I didn't post the String.valueOf(C) because he said that he has a stack of char, so I think that he should know that the result must be a single-digit integer

Comment: @Alessio Yeah I noticed that too. Question looks like part of some form of calculator so I'm hope the OP is aware of any multi-digit possibilities. which could come about very easily, especially with `*`